# Asynchronous update/ deletion of data

Tags: jquery, json, coldfusion

I still consider myself a beginner when it comes to JQUERY+Coldfusion...so I'd like to ask for help/ direction on this.

I'm trying to make a search page of items that acts similar to gmail. There is a delete button and basically it asynchronously deletes an item from the database and should update the page asynchronously (removing said item from list). I've gotten kind of close as to figuring out how to do this. However, now I'm rethinking how I should go about this.

Currently, my code updates the database and then re-runs the query from a CFC. I'm starting to wonder if I should not do this. Would it be easier to convert the query to a JSON format and have jquery/javascript remove things from the what the client sees and then also run a deletion query?

If JSON seems to be the answer can someone point me to a good place to learn how to manipulate JSON? I've looked at a few examples and most of it looks like built in json parsing functions, then the rest is just getting it in the format you need/want.

Comment: You may want to consider using the MVVM pattern for your javascript. Basically you maintain your list of items in a javascript array, and each time that array is modified, you re-render the UI and fire of some JSON to the server. A good library for this is [Knockout.JS](http://knockoutjs.com/).

Comment: You usually don't need to manipulate JSON.  It is just a format that can easily be converted JavaScript Object/Array <-> CF Struct/Array.  Usually you manipulate it in the Obj/Struct/Array level and Serialize the Obj/Struct/Array into JSON.

Comment: I see...but beyond that...my real question is should I use JSON to do what I am trying to do? :)

@Paperjam Also, I'm kind of hesitant to use libraries just yet. I like to get a full understanding of what I'm doing before I get stuff to do it for me.

Comment: Are you using Ajax to do the delete or are you doing a round trip to the server every time (I.E. doing a form submit)?  I think the answer to that question would help formulate the best answer for you.

Comment: @bittersweetryan I use ajax to load a page that has a cfinvoke of a cfc that gets the requests. When this query is returned, it populates a table that is on this loaded page as well. Also, when a search string is submitted, it sends the data with the .load and then the table is populated with the results. (If the data is defined it runs the search method instead of just the get all.)

Comment: json is just the messaging format.  It can be XML, or Plain Text, whatever u prefer.  But you need to use AJAX for sure..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way we handle this is simple:

- If someone deletes something via the UI we make a Ajax call to delete that object / row / whatever in the database.
- The javascript callback from the Ajax call **if successful** will then remove that element from the UI.

So esentially you are keeping the UI and the database in sync. This is an efficient way as it ensures you are only running essential queries against the database (e.g. delete v delete / read all again). It is also snappier for the user.

Hope that helps!